# What are small or tiny creatures that paralyze?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, conditions

In Adventurers League, there is a new option to submit modules for conventions that can become Adventurers League “certified.” One requirement is that only existing creatures can be used.

We have an adventure that calls for a small scorpion sized creature that paralyzes but now need to find a substitute because Monster Manual scorpions have poison without paralyzing effects.

What are viable current Adventurers League legal creatures that are small or tiny (such that a sleep spell could knock out a dozen of them) but that also paralyze?

Addendum:
Per a question below, yes, falling unconscious would actually functionally work as well.

Comment: A number of the MM bugs paralyze only if they reduce a creature to 0 HP. Does that work?

Comment: We would need the savings throws as in paralyzation poison (i.e. before 0 h.p.)

Answer (score 4):

While not paralysis the Sprite can knock people out and only has 1d4 of health.

Their shortbows read:

> Hit:1 piercing damage, and the target must succeed on a DC 10 Constitution saving throw or become poisoned for 1 minute. If its saving throw result is 5 or lower, the target falls unconscious for the same duration, or until it takes damage or another creature takes and action to shake it awake.

The Pseudodragon has a similar poison lasting 1 hour but has more health at 2d4+2.

Comment: Interesting...we will be curious to see if CCC modules would enable the change of the Sprite into the form of a flying insect. The bow attack would need to be changed to some type of shot stinger and its spell effects would need to be neutralized. Not sure if it would be too much of a change.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there are no creatures that are Tiny or Small that can paralyze.

If it didn't need the paralysed condition exactly, you could consider the Pseudodragon which has the ability to cause creatures to fall unconscious with its sting.

Comment: Nice - yes actually falling unconscious would functionally work as a game mechanic. I believe AL rules for CCC modules allow you to say "stats same as X"...will have to check. In this case, the scorpions may be able to have "stats same as pseudodragon but without flying."

Answer (score 0):

If the criteria doesn't require the sleep spell to take out exactly a dozen, another option is the Homunculus.

They are tiny. They have 5 hit points. Their attack causes targets to go unconscious:

> Bite. Melee Weapon Attack: +4 to hit, reach 5 ft. , one creature. Hit:1 piercing damage, and the target must succeed on a DC 10 Constitution saving throw or be poisoned for 1 minute. If the saving throw fails by 5 or more, the target is instead poisoned for 5 (1d10) minutes and unconscious while poisoned in this way.

Additionally, they have a telepathic bond to their Master which may be a useful addition.